# Huawei Map Kit Directions API does not show Route planning in the US

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-map-kit

I am using Huawei Map Kit REST Directions API for route planning in my Android app. The details of the Directions APIs can be found at the links below:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/web-diretions-api-introduction-0000001050178120-V5

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/directions-walking-0000001050161494-V5

The Directions API works well in my app for route planning in most of countries and regions. But it seems that the function of Directions API does not work in the US. In other words, it does not show route between two places on Huawei Map. After checking the supported countries/regions in Huawei developer website, the country of the US is supported by Map Kit. Why does the route planning not work in the US?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and sorry for the inconvenience. The route planning function in the US region has been reported to the map product department. It is expected to be released in HMS Core 5.3.0 in the middle of May.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your feedback, the current route planning function in Directions API of Map Kit does not support the route planning of locations in the United States for the time being. We are now completing the part of the function to support the US.
We are sorry for not clearly stated on the website and will refresh the information on the website as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks Zinna! The answer is very helpful.